Compairing two groups with paired data
I have two groups of samples: healthy and diseased groups. Each had an X treatment. So, I have a healthy baseline and healthy X treatment. The same for the disease group. Which is the best way to analyze them? If I use one-way ANOVA, it only measures the mean. But it doesn't take into account that they are paired measurements. The healthy group did change, but its mean is lower; therefore, it is not assumed to be significant. If I do a paired T-test, I get how each group responded to the treatment but cannot compare healthy vs disease. Hope you can help me.

It sounds like you want to compare healthy and disesed individuals, before and after the treatment?   This sounds like a 2 x 2 repeated measures ANOVA. If you are using R this is easiest using nlme or lmer with a model like lmer(response ~health*treatment + (1|ID))

It depends on what you are trying to prove.
To show that traetment X improved the Diseased group more than the Healthy group (if they are Healthy, treatment X should not have a big effect), you could compute the "Before-After" measures for both groups (Healthy and Diseased), and then use a 2-sample t-test (Welch version) to compare the mean change.
If you are trying to prove that treatment X was effective, just run a paired t-test on the Diseased (but then you should have used a placebo group, not a healthy group).
...cont...

...cont...
If you are trying to prove that the Diseased are "cured" (as good as Healthy), run a 2-sample t comparing Diseased after to Healthy before.
Honestly, it is not clear from the question what the purpose of the study/data is. Can you clarify?

You can use at least

repeated-measures mixed ANOVA with healthy vs. disease as between-subject factor and time as within-subject factor,

Analysis of Covariance (ANCOVA) with baseline scores as a covariate, healthy vs. disease as between-subject factor and post-treatment scores as the dependent,


(here is a very clear presentation regarding the differences between 1 and 2 when dealing with pre-post data; note that this deals with the more typical situation where the treatment (control vs. treatment) is the between-subject factor and the groups are initially similar whereas you have initially two groups and the treatment is the same. However, the analyses suggested work for your data too).

multilevel regression with time*health group interaction and a random intercept of participant as suggested by N Brouwer in a comment. In your situation this is pretty much the same thing as repeated-measures ANOVA (1), but multilevel regression handles missing data better than ANOVA.

